# Introducing ordered pairs in an axiomatic way

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Suppose that in $ZFC$ we have introduced ordered pairs not in the usual way as  $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ but axiomatically, by *extending* $ZFC$ by adding to $ZFC$ a new binary functional symbol $g$
and a corresponding axiom:
    $\forall a,b,c,d( g(a,b) = g(c,d) \rightarrow a=c  \wedge  b=d)$.

The main advantage of this approach is absence of so called "junk" theorems
- see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems.

Let us write instead of $g(x,y)$ just $(x,y)$

Question 1. Will be the formula $\forall S,u((S,u) \notin S)$  a theorem of the extended theory?

Question 2. Are there textbooks where ordered pairs were introduced in a similar axiomatic way?

Comment: Things like this are done in type theory. In other words, given two types (you can read this as sets if you want, but that is only a half truth), $A$, and $B$, then we have ways of constructing new types, such as $A\times B$, $Functions(A,B)$ (this type is often written as $A\to B$). We then give rules about how to work with the type, and how to construct terms (read as elements if you must) of the types. Also in the set theory, ETCS the product of two sets is defined categorically.

Comment: See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS for a reference on ECTS and the first chapter of here http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/ for the type theory bit.

Comment: IMO it's better to introduce a second type as well -- to have have the class $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets, and $\mathbf{Set}^2$ of ordered pairs, and $g : \mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}^2$. Then, it *doesn't even make sense* to write down an expression like the one below. (for completeness, you would need more tuple types as well) $$\forall S \in \mathbf{Set} \forall u \in \mathbf{Set}: g(S,u) \notin S$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer to Question 1 is no. Here's one way to see this: take any model $M\vDash ZFC$ and let $f$ be any one-one function from $M\times M$ to $M$ ($f$ will exist by the axiom of choice). We then modify $f$ to a new function $f^*$ so that $f^*(\langle 1, 0\rangle) = 0_M$ and $f^*(f^-1(0_M)) = f(\langle 1, 0\rangle)$. Then we have the following:

(1) $M$, with $f^*$ as the interpretation of $g$, models ZFC plus your pairing axiom; and:

(2) $M$, with $f^*$ as the interpretation of $g$, thinks that $g(1, 0) \in 1$.