# Problems with introducing ordered pairs axiomatically

Tags: set-theory

(See also [Introducing ordered pairs in an axiomatic way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615157/introducing-ordered-pairs-in-an-axiomatic-way)).

Many feel that the usual way to introduce *ordered pairs* in set theory following K.Kuratowski as 
$(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ is rather unnatural (B.Russell called Kuratowski's definition a trick).
But the main drawback of this definition is the emergence of so called "junk" theorems - see

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems

So it seems reasonable to try to introduce ordered pairs in an axiomatic way,

for example, to extend  $ZFC$ by adding to $ZFC$ a new binary functional symbol $g$ 
and an obvious axiom:
Axiom1 := $\forall a,b,c,d( g(a,b) = g(c,d) \rightarrow a=c \wedge b=d)$.

But for further development of set theory we need more axioms, for example
Axiom2 :=  $\forall a,b(g(a,b) \in P(P(a \cup b)))$.

So my question is:

Are necessary some other axioms for the symbol $g$?

Comment: Your axioms allow a model where $g(a,b)=\lbrace\lbrace a\rbrace,\lbrace a,b\rbrace,\emptyset\rbrace$.  Is it important to rule this out?

Comment: Why do you need the second axiom?  To preserve the definition of the cumulative hierarchy?

Comment: The second axiom appears to be disposable; the theory will have multiple models anyway, and all this does is rule some of them out --- to no apparent purpose.

Comment: Why stop with ordered pairs? Why not introduce real numbers axiomatically, to do away with such "junk propositions" as $\pi^e\in e^\pi$ which is probably false but IIRC a famous open question.

Comment: @Steven: 1) The formula $g(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\},0 \}$ will not be a theorem of the extended theory $ZFC_g$ - as well as the formula $g(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: @arsmath,@Steven: Try to prove in $ZFC+Axiom1$ the formula $\forall S,u((S,u) \notin S)$. (see the reference above to math.stackexchange).

Comment: @bof: I agree that real (as well as integer) numbers should be be introduced axiomaticallly.

Comment: Why should we care about "natural?"  If it works, it works.

Comment: @VictorMakarov:  Yes, perhaps my point was obscure.  I was trying to point out that  Axiom 2 serves no purpose.  All it does is rule out some models.  But if your goal is to arbitrarily rule out some models, you might as well arbitrarily rule out some others, such as those in which in which $g(a,b)=\lbrace\lbrace a\rbrace,\lbrace a,b\rbrace,\emptyset\rbrace$ .  In other words, my point was that it's *not* important to rule this out, and, for exactly the same reason, it's not important to impose Axiom 2.

Comment: I used to ask questions like this all the time. Lately, though, I've been thinking that ZFC is *inherently* full of junk theorems - because everything it specified up to equality rather than isomorphism - and that if you're not comfortable with this, changing foundations is probably a better option than trying to change ZFC. To this end, you may want to read about [SEAR](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR) or more ambitiously, [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS). Of course, these latter systems have their own issues.

Comment: @user18921 "Junk theorems" aren't a real issue.  A set of ordered pairs is a set with certain properties.  ZFC allows you to prove this set exists and that it's unique up to the appropriate notion of isomorphism.  It doesn't compel you take a certain set to be "the set of ordered pairs".  Junk theorems arise when you fix a choice.

Answer (score 6):

There is no problem introducing a new symbol $g$ for a pairing function to ZFC. Let's call ZFC<sub>$g$</sub> the theory with the new symbol $g$ together with the new axiom $$\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \forall y_1 \forall y_2 (g(x_1,x_2) = g(y_1,y_2) \to x_1 = y_ 1 \land x_2 = y_2)$$ and also with the comprehension and replacement axioms expanded to include formulas mentioning this new function symbol $g$.

Since $\newcommand{\ZFC}{\mathsf{ZFC}}\ZFC$ has a definable pairing function (e.g. the Kuratowski pairing function) this new theory is $\ZFC_g$ relatively consistent with $\ZFC$. In fact, since every model of $\ZFC$ can be expanded to a model of $\ZFC_g$, it is conservative over $\ZFC$: every statement that doesn't involve $g$ that is provable in $\ZFC_g$ was already provable in $\ZFC$. In other words, $\ZFC_g$ is a 100% harmless extension of $\ZFC$.

This trick does avoid most junk *theorems*, e.g. $\varnothing \in g(\varnothing,\varnothing)$ is neither provable nor disprovable in $\ZFC_g$. However, it does not avoid junk *facts*, e.g. $\varnothing \in g(\varnothing,\varnothing)$ has to be true or false in any model of $\ZFC_g$. As with any conventions for tuples, functions, sequences, and so on, $\ZFC$ is completely agnostic as to how these are defined, it is only the fact that at least one encoding exists that really matters.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is known as [structural set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory). There are many possible formulation, but usually they do not stop with just having axiomatic ordered pairs. For one example, see the [SEAR entry in nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR), as well as Todd Trimble's entries on ETCS ([part 1](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+on+ETCS+I), [part 2](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+on+ETCS+II), [part 3](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+on+ETCS+III)). Part I has an explicit axiomatization of ordered pairs, look up "Axiom of products".

Briefly, ordered pairs are axiomatized as follows:

> For all sets $a$ and $b$ there is a set $c$ and two functions $p_1 : c \to a$ and $p_2 : c \to b$, such that for all $x \in a$ and $y \in b$ there exists a unique $z \in c$, such that
>   $p_1(z) = x$ and $p_2(z) = y$.

I am skipping over a couple of details that Todd properly attends to. Your function symbol $g$ corresponds to the unique existence of $z$ above.

Comment: Andrej, this doesn't answer the question as posed. The OP is asking about a global pairing function, not about the existence of products, which only gives local pairing functions.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, it does however constitute an intelligent and useful response the presumed motivation behind the question, namely the so-called "junk theorems" of material set theory.

Comment: Anyone who discovers the possiblity of axiomatizing abstractly ordered pairs should be shown the idea that all of set theory can be done that way.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I approve of this programme, because coding and representation are frequently necessary in set theory, and yield such arbitrary theorems every time. But to answer your question...

You will need a way to distinguish the $g(a,b)$ from other sets. So, in particular, an axiom like $\emptyset\not\in g(a,b)$ seems necessary. Moreover, knowing that g(a,b) is a finite set will be useful.

Comment: "Coding and representation are frequently necessary in set theory, and yield such arbitrary theorems every time." I think the idea is not to do away with coding and representation, but rather, to do it *better*. For example, rather than using Kuratowski's idea as the *definition* of ordered pairs, we use it as a proof that our extension of ZFC (i.e. ZFC+ordered pairs) is in fact harmless.