# When defining ordered pairs axiomatically, is their existence an axiom?

Tags: logic, axioms, foundations

If one wishes to introduce ordered pairs to ZFC as a new sort, rather than constructing them as sets (e.g., using the Kuratowski pairing function) within ZFC, [it is possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617064/111520) to add a binary function symbol, e.g., "$g$", which given any pair of objects, returns an object of type "ordered pair."

One then includes the axiom that the output of $g$ satisfies the characteristic property of the ordered pair, i.e., that for all objects $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, and $b_2$, $g(a_1,a_2) = g(b_1, b_2)$ if and only if $a_1 = a_2$ and $b_1 = b_2$.

However, is it also necessary to include as an axiom that ordered pairs exist?
Terence Tao writes on page 62 of *Analysis I*, where he defines ordered pairs,

> Strictly speaking, this definition is partly an axiom, because we have simply postulated that given any two objects $x$ and $y$, that an object of the form $(x, y)$ exists.

Similarly, Robert Wolf writes as the fourth of the "Set axioms" listed in Appendix 1, *A General-Purpose Axiom System for Mathematics*, on page 372 of Proof, *Logic, and Conjecture / The Mathematician's Toolbox*,

> For every $x$ and $y$, the ordered pair $(x,y)$ exists.

But isn't that $g(a,b)$ exists for all objects $a$ and $b$ implicit in the fact that $g$ is defined as a binary function symbol?
For example, in Peano arithmetic, with the unary successor function symbol $S$, I don't think it's necessary to explicitly axiomatize that $S(n)$ exists for all natural numbers $n$--isn't this implicit in the fact that $S$ is a unary function symbol?

Comment: The correct analogy in your $S(n)$ example is that I must know $n$ exists before I can consider $S(n)$. If you introduce the function $g(a,b)$ (which might more accurately be written as $g((a,b))$, then what is it defined on? What am I allowed to put into it? What is $(a,b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you have a function symbol, then it is implicit that any terms that you can produce with it exists and well-defined when you interpret the term.

Specifically, if $g$ is the symbol of your ordered pair operator, and $M$ is a structure to your language $\{\in,g\}$, then you require that $g$ is defined on $M^2$, so for every $x,y\in M$, $g(x,y)$ is some element of $M$, which in other words means that it exists.

Comment: The question seems to be more whether we need to postulate that $(x,y)$ exists (i.e., $M^2$ exists) before we can talk about $g$ or $g(x,y)$.

Comment: That is not part of the theory *at all*. That is part of the meta-theory.